Diplay media notification in flutter
I use the just_audio package in my flutter app to play musics.
How can I display a music player notification in the user's notification bar; something like the picture below:
I think one of the possible ways is to use the local notification package but I don't know how to display media using it

add these dependencies
just_audio: ^0.9.0+1
just_audio_background: ^0.3.2

make instance for it
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

final AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();

void playMusic(String audioUrl) async {
  await player.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(audioUrl));
  player.play();
}

that's how you can done it
import 'package:just_audio_background/just_audio_background.dart';

void setupBackgroundPlayback() async {
  await initializeJustAudioBackground();
  player.playbackEventStream.listen((event) {
    if (event.state == PlayerState.playing) {
      showNotification(player.playing);
    } else if (event.state == PlayerState.paused) {
      removeNotification();
    }
  });
}

and for notification handling:
import 'package:flutter_notifications/flutter_notifications.dart';

void showNotification(Playing playing) async {
  final notification = FlutterNotification(
    id: 1,
    title: playing.title,
    body: playing.artist,
    android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
      channelId: 'your_channel_id',
      channelName: 'Music Player',
      icon: Icon(Icons.music_note),
      playAction: NotificationAction(
        // Handle play/pause on notification tap
      ),
      pauseAction: NotificationAction(
        // Handle play/pause on notification tap
      ),
    ),
  );
  await FlutterNotifications.show(notification);
}

must add permissions required by plugin
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE" />


This solution has an error in the latest versions of the packages. Will you please test this with new versions?

currently i'm unable to !
but you can try by adjsuting asper plugin refers.
best of luck
